# Synch NSUserDefaults value on language change and compare

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nslocalizedstring

EDIT: On change language to Hindi...i want to change the value of saved NSUserdefault as well! how do i do it? 
I have create a singleton class which save the value for e.g.:
singleton.userStatus=NSLocalizedString(@"yes", nil);

I have set

`"yes" = @"YES";` 
in hindi
`"yes" = @"हाँ";` 
in my NSLocalizedString

and

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:singleton.userStatus forKey:@"USER_STATUS"];
```

Now i am comparing it

```
NSString *checkStatus = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"USER_STATUS"]; // i have set its default value YES


    if ([checkStatus isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"yes", nil)])
    {
      // not comes here  
    }
else
    {
     //
    }
```

Comment: I d recomlend adding a breakpoint and inspect the  variables or log them to the console for more details, my be you are not syncronizing the userdefault after adding the string.

Comment: synchronising done

Comment: why don't you save an english value in user defaults and use the localized value when you need it?